# Using self-hosted OWIN

Tags: c#

I have implemented the following in order to handle JS XHR requests coming from HTML pages. Is there a better way to do this with OWIN?

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
        {
            FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(string.Format("{0}{1}Web{1}Dashboard", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
        });
        app.Use<Middleware>();
    }
}

public class Middleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private readonly List<string> _knownRequests = new List<string>
    {
        "Request"
    };

    public Middleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        #region Invoke Next Context

        await Next.Invoke(context);

        #endregion

        #region Handle Request

        var request = context.Request;
        var response = context.Response;
        var path = request.Path.Value.TrimStart('/');
        if (!_knownRequests.Contains(path))
            return;

        response.StatusCode = 200;

        switch (path)
        {
            case "Request":
            {
                await response.WriteAsync("RESPONSE!");
                break;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Only focusing on the code in question (not on OWIN)**

Using `region` outside of methods is discussed controversially but using `region`'s inside a method is clearly a code smell. It indicates that a method is too big or worse that a method has too many responsibilities.

---

Instead of adding `"Request"` to the `List` and using the string "Request"  in the `switch` you should declare a const holding "Request" and which you should add to the `List` and use it in the `switch` to reduce the possibility of spelling errors.

---

Using a `switch` for a single case should be better changed to a simple `if` statement.

---

You should use braces `{}` for single statements `if`'s too. This will make your code less error prone.

---

Variables should be declared as near as possible to their usage. So changing

> ```
> var request = context.Request;
> var response = context.Response;
> var path = request.Path.Value.TrimStart('/');
> if (!_knownRequests.Contains(path))
>     return;
>
> response.StatusCode = 200;
> ```

to

```
var request = context.Request;
var path = request.Path.Value.TrimStart('/');
if (!_knownRequests.Contains(path))
{
    return;
}

var response = context.Response;
response.StatusCode = 200;
```

would be better.

---

Using the `var` keyword should be only done when the type of the right hand side of the declaration is obvious.
This is only true for the last usage here:

> ```
> var request = context.Request;
> var response = context.Response;
> var path = request.Path.Value.TrimStart('/');
> ```

so better change it to

```
IOwinRequest request = context.Request;
IOwinResponse response = context.Response;
var path = request.Path.Value.TrimStart('/');
```

but using the `request` does not add to much value here,because it is only used once, so you could just change it to

```
IOwinResponse response = context.Response;
var path = context.Request.Path.Value.TrimStart('/');
```

Comment: what about owin ?

Comment: No idea/knowledge about it